# Android Studio --- Navigation Drawer Activity, Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio, I used Eclipse before.
Today when I am starting a new project,with Blank Activity, and the Navigation Type is Navigation Drawer.
But when I am running the project, it won`t work. And the some wrong message come on logcat.
Here is the log.Can anyone tell the problem? Thanks.

```
    01-11 20:37:38.579  14409-14409/com.lee.myapplicationdrawer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lee.myapplicationdrawer/com.lee.myapplicationdrawer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:318)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:111)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at com.lee.myapplicationdrawer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5184)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.lee.myapplicationdrawer.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:82)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2553)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:224)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:232)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:147)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:199)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:285)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:835)
            at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2672)
            at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:648)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:170)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setHasOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:803)
            at com.lee.myapplicationdrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreate(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:82)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1477)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:893)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
            at android.vi
01-11 20:37:38.749  11330-11330/? E/Launcher﹕ Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: accessibility_en
```

abled

Comment: post the fragment xml

Comment: Post your xml and relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a null pointer while inflating your menu on onCreateOptionsMenu, post your code if you don't mind. Post the code for MainActivity class and NavigationDrawerFragment class and the xml files.